# Pose mirroring not mirroring y-axis position

Tags: animation, bones, fcurves

I'm learning to animate a creature I recently created and I need your help. I know that it's possible to mirror poses by naming the bones of the armature correctly using the following naming system: example.L and example.R

I've named my bones so the mirror pose action would work properly. The body of the creature is also done by using the mirror modifier (so it should be symmetrical along the y-axis). In addition, the weight paint of the bones is also mirrored.

I have an IK target that somehow won't mirror the Y-axis location. I don' t understand what may cause it. There's no lock icon next to the y-axis location parameter which is strange. Here's a picture to visualize the problem:

[image]

Here's a picture of a graph - the green line shows the y-axis location frame by frame. It shouldn't be constantly linear as you can see the movement of the other leg.

[image]

The leg animation.

[image]

EDIT: Added few pictures of the movement after y-axis position started working but there are still few problems with the pose mirroring.

Animation from the back of the creature:

[image]

Animation from the side view:

[image]

Comment: Blender's armatures are mirror along X axis

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to solve the problem. I am not sure whether it was because of the wrong axis or just some kind of bugged pose. I deleted the Foot_Controller_Back.L bone from the dope sheet and added a new instance of it. After that it was all fine. Thanks for the answer once again  :)

Comment: I also rotated the armature so it was on X axis, I forgot to mention it :)

Comment: Hmm... Sorry to mention, but I showed my gratitude too early. It seems something is still wrong. I rotated my armature so it's properly positioned along the X axis. the IK target now moves along the y axis properly but the pose mirroring is still problematic, it doesn' t work as it should. I've added a new animation to the question.